# Python: How to save for loop string values into csv file?

Tags: python, string, csv

I would like to save my strings into a csv file. 
Given the code below, there is a closed file issue, how can I save the list of strings into csv file? I don't understand why is this not working.

**Code**

```
import csv
with open('onehot.csv','wb') as testfile:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(testfile)

collection = ['hey', '5', 'd']
for x in collection:
    csv_writer.writerow(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent your code block to be *within* the `with` statement scope, and wrap each string in a list to make it an actual *row*:

```
import csv
with open('onehot.csv','wb') as testfile:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(testfile)

    collection = ['hey', '5', 'd']
    for x in collection:
        csv_writer.writerow([x])
```

File objects are *context managers*, and the `with` statement informs them when the context is exited (the block under the `with` statement has ended or an exception was raised). File objects respond by *closing the file*, so you can't write to it anymore outside of a `with` block.